# What is $\mathbf Z[x,y]/(y+1)$ isomorphic to?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> What is $\mathbf Z[x,y]/(y+1)$ is isomorphic to?

I  was  wondering about this question and I think the answer must be $\mathbf{Z}[x]$. How can I show that this is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}[x]$? Any hints?

Comment: This hurts to read. Would you mind fixing it please?

Comment: im sorry @GuidoA...as  i don't  know  how  to show this

Comment: It takes *more* effort to write a question like you did, so I'm confident that you can.

Comment: okk thanks @GuidoA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a homomorphism $\mathbf{Z}[x,y] \to \mathbf{Z}[x]$ mapping $f(x,y)$ to $f(x,-1)$. What are its kernel and image?

Comment: thanks @arkeet i gots  its